# Update jQuery Datepicker UI without Changing the Associated Input

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm currently working on a project where I need to use jQuery datepicker. Everything works beautifully, except for one requirement... the user needs to be able to enter a "smartdate". A smart date is a shorthand syntax for easily generating a date X number of days in the future or the past. The syntax for entering the date is a plus sign (+) or minus sign (-) followed by an integer, representing the number of days from today. I've already set the `constrainInput` flag on my datepicker configuration to allow the user to input the signs. My problem is this: At each instance of a numeric character being entered, I want the calendar to update to show the currently "selected" day, but at the point where you use the setDate operation, the datepicker takes control of the input and alters the text the user is entering. I delved into the source code a bit and found that the _setDate method has a second parameter called `noChange` but passing the flag in the following manner has no effect:

`$ele.datepicker('setDate', date, true);`

I'm not familiar enough with the various levels of abstraction that jQuery UI and the datepicker plugin themselves throw around this component so it's really hard for me to devise a solution without spending way too much time digging through the source code.

Is there anyone out there that can offer me a bit of help? It would be much appreciated!

And for those that would like to see some code, you can check out my codepen here: ['Smart Date Module'](http://codepen.io/THEtheChad/pen/Ggjzrv)

The second input is the user input, the first one is the model backing in it Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand your question but why don't you just set the user value back in the input after calling the datePicker `setDate`? This will update the datePicker date after each keypress and will keep the user value in the input:

```
$($ele[0]).datepicker('setDate', date);
$ele.val(value);
```

I updated your <kbd>[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBoqPz)</kbd> to reflect the change.

Tell me if this is not what you expect.

Comment: That's exactly the type of functionality I'm looking for. I didn't realize the "answer" would be so simple. I put answer in quotes because I still feel like it's a bit hacky, but thinking about it more, I don't see any long term issues. I think I was worried about a feedback loop, but since setting the value of the input doesn't fire the change event, it works. Go figure! Thanks for your help!